# rCharts in Shiny AWS

Tags: r, rcharts, shiny-server

Tried renderchart2 to overcome an issue with shiny and rcharts but getting the follwoing error:

```
Loading required package: RCurl
Loading required package: bitops
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘reshape2’
Calls: runApp ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

My deployment is in AWS and the examples packages are working a charm in /srv/...

Considering it is a copy paste job from https://github.com/ramnathv/rChartsShiny/tree/gh-pages/rChartOECD why is reshape2 casuing an error?

Comment: Do you have the `reshape2` package installed?

Comment: haha sorry, rookie mistake, the list of install.packages failed because of of dependencies. Assumed it at installed it but it hadn't.

Comment: I am still trying to get dimple to run properly using AWS set up. Keeps throwing errors with missing `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` Is there something that is missing? I am using the custom html to load the charts

Comment: Unless you share your html, it is very hard for any of us to hel you debug.